# how to add an error message to my errror messages <ul> in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I generate a custom error message from the errors which I get from codeigniter form validation:

```
$this->message->set_error ( $this->form_validation->error_array () );
$message = $this->message->get_message ();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($message); die;
$this->data ['message'] = $message;
```

the  `$message` is this

```
<div class="errormsg message">
<p>
<em>Error</em>
</p>
<ul>
<li>The First Name field is required.</li>
<li>The Last Name field is required.</li>
<li>The Date of birth field is required.</li>
<li>The Email address field is required.</li>
<li>The Password field is required.</li>
<li>The Password Confirmation field is required.</li>
<li>The City field is required.</li>
<li>The State field is required.</li>
<li>The captureCode field is required.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i have another error string

```
$err = 'Age is below 14';
```

I want to add this `$err` to the `<ul>`
so the resulting `<ul>` will be

```
<ul>
<li>The First Name field is required.</li>
<li>The Last Name field is required.</li>
<li>The Date of birth field is required.</li>
<li>The Email address field is required.</li>
<li>The Password field is required.</li>
<li>The Password Confirmation field is required.</li>
<li>The City field is required.</li>
<li>The State field is required.</li>
<li>The captureCode field is required.</li>
<li>Age is below 14</li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using something like DOMDocument to append the element, you can use a simple string replace:

```
$message = '<div class="errormsg message">
<p>
<em>Error</em>
</p>
<ul>
<li>The First Name field is required.</li>
</ul>
</div>';
$err = 'Age is below 14';
$message = str_replace( '</ul>', '<li>' . $err . '</li></ul>', $message);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tbIm6V)

Comment: perfect. i understand . very simple and useful technique . thanks